# Mediawiki Infobox: How to display images

Tags: image, mediawiki, infobox, semantic-mediawiki

I can not get images in info boxes of my MediaWiki (1.29.1, Semantic MediaWiki installed) to show up. It just renders the filename as text.

My info box template:

```
<includeonly>{| class="wikitable"
! Name
| [[Initiative_Name::{{{Name|}}}]] 
|-
! Logo
| [[Initiative_Logo::{{{Initiative_Logo}}}]]
...
|}
</includeonly>
```

And here´s what i use on the page where the info box should be displayed:

```
{{Infobox
|Name=My Name
|Logo=Logo_Kasimir.png
...
}}
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it, the **File:**-part was missing

```
|Logo=File:Logo_Kasimir.png
```